# Add loggedout class on body using a function or JS

Tags: functions, jquery

Is it possible to add a class `loggedout` on the body of every page for all logged out users using a function or JS?

My theme already adds a class 'loggedin' for all logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your theme is using the [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function to output classes. You can [add a filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) to remove or add your own classes.

```
function wpd_logged_out_body_class( $classes ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
        $classes[] = 'loggedout';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpd_logged_out_body_class' );
```

Comment: yes this does the trick..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [body class filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) and add your own classes. The example below uses `is_user_logged_in();` function which returns true or false.

This can be added to your themes function.php file. Hope this helps.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'your_custom_body_classes');
function your_custom_body_classes($classes) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $classes[] = 'loggedout';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```